# Why did Aragorn decide to ride to Dunharrow instead of to Minas Tirith?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings

Why is it that in *The Return of the King*, Chapter 2, Aragorn wanted to travel to Dunharrow and not Minas Tirith after parting with Théoden?

Comment: Dunharrow leads to both the Paths of the Dead and Minas Tirith. Aragorn, Gimli and Legolas left Theoden early to pass through Dunharrow to get to the Paths of the Dead and use the Dead to attack the Corsairs and prevent them from attacking Minas Tirith before Theoden and the Rohirrim could arrive to help Gondor.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer! So to summarise, both groups departed from Helms Deep  but while Theadon  (with Halbarad Dunadan) was going to stop their and gather forces and then go to Dunharrow to then go Minas Tirith, Aragon was going straight from Helms Deap to Dunharrow to then go to the path of the Dead, correct?

Comment: Yes, that's right, he'd come to the decision-point and made-up his mind to fulfill his destiny to take on the mantle of King - facing the Army of the dead was a necessary step on that path, and all the better for the fight to come.

Comment: Great, thank you for the clarification. The two parties taking different routes to Dunharrow and then once again taking different routes to Minas Tirith!

Comment: Well, the dead were more loyal to him than the citizens of Gondor, so he went where he can get troops asap :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Aragorn had always intended to travel to Minas Tirith, although initially he could not see the way and knew only that it was dark, although he was aware that he had prepared for it.

> ‘As for the king, he will go to the muster that he commanded at Edoras, four nights from now. And there, I think, he will hear tidings of war, and the Riders of Rohan will go down to Minas Tirith. But for myself, and any that will go with me . . .’
> ‘I for one!’ cried Legolas. ‘And Gimli with him!’ said the Dwarf.
> ‘Well, for myself,’ said Aragorn, ‘**it is dark before me. I must go down also to Minas Tirith, but I do not yet see the road.** An hour long prepared approaches.’
> <sub>Return of the King: Book V, Chapter 2: The Passing of the Grey Company</sub>

It is not until the arrival of the Grey Company and the brothers Elrohir and Elladan that the suggestion to take the paths of the dead had entered Aragorn's mind. It is at this point he first considers it, although he is hesitant to heed it.

> Elrohir said to him: ‘I bring word to you from my father: The days are short. **If thou art in haste, remember the Paths of the Dead.’**
> ‘Always my days have seemed to me too short to achieve my desire,’ answered Aragorn. **‘But great indeed will be my haste ere I take that road.’**
> <sub>ibid.</sub>

When Aragorn confronts Théoden and Éomer about their plans, he is told they only expect to reach Dunharrow in three days time. However, this is far longer than the time Aragorn has, as such he decides to instead ride openly and swiftly to Dunharrow to take the Paths of the Dead

> ‘Three days,’ he murmured, ‘and the muster of Rohan will only be begun. But I see that it cannot now be hastened.’ [...] ‘Then, by your leave, lord, I must take new counsel for myself and my kindred. We must ride our own road [...] I will ride east by the swiftest way, and I will take the Paths of
> the Dead.’
> <sub>ibid.</sub>

Finally, part of the reason to take the Paths of the Dead is to reach the coastlands. This is not only where the Stone of Erech lies, but also where populations of Gondorians still remain and Aragorn can, with the help of the Army of the Dead, drive away the Corsairs at Pelargir and free Gondor's Southern Army to sail North in aid of Minas Tirith.

> ‘I have no help to send, therefore I must go myself,’ said Aragorn. ‘But there is only one way through the mountains that will bring me to the coastlands before all is lost. That is the Paths of the Dead.’
> <sub>ibid.</sub>

Comment: Than you! But why does Aragorn ‘yet see the road’? Can he not just go by the great west road that will directly take him there? Although the part about gathering forces of the Dead clarifies that I guess. Still, what is the big deal with Dunharrow. Would they not want to go to either Edoras or straight to Minas Tirith?

Comment: Hold up, I’ll make that a question, would appreciate the help!

Comment: Why Aragorn can't see the road in effect means he's unsure where he should go. He could take the direct route but it isn't beneficial. He still has to worry about the Corsair attack from the South and getting the Southern Army to Minas Tirith!

Comment: Probably also metaphorical in a sense. Should I arrive in Minas Tirith in another Thorongil-like guise and offer my service, or should I reveal my true identity immediately (or even have word of my approach precede me).