# Where did Halbarad and the Grey Company catch up with Théoden's party?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings

In *The Return of the King*, Chapter 2, while riding through Rohan in the company of Théoden, Éomer, Aragorn and co. a group of riders is seen passing them. It is revealed that these Riders are the Grey Company in search of Aragorn. Where in Rohan is it that the Grey Company and Théoden's party meet?

Comment: I have removed the second question, for one because ideally each post contains only one question, and secondly because it has been addressed in your previous question: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/251702

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### At the 'Fords of Isen' on the edge of Rohan's borders

Théoden's party had been overtaken between Dol Baran and the Hornburg. Specifically, it was shortly after they passed the "Fords of Isen"

> They had not long passed the mounds at the Fords of Isen, when a Rider galloped up from the rear of their line.
> 'My lord,' he said to the king, 'there are horsemen behind us. As we crossed the fords I thought that I heard them. Now we are sure. They are overtaking us, riding hard.'
> <sub>The Return of the King: Book V, Chapter 2: The Passing of the Grey Company</sub>

Éomer informs Halbarad that his company had just entered Rohan: when they'd crossed the Fords they had in fact entered Rohan.

> When you crossed the fords yonder you entered it.
> <sub>ibid.</sub>

Comment: Thank you, you just grinned through two such long answer! Thank you!  So it the Grey Company they are called, makes sense.