# What is the importance of Dunharrow?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings

In *The Return of the King* Chapter 2, "The Passing of the Grey Company", heavy emphasis is put on Dunharrow. Aragorn must ride there in haste [before travelling to Minas Tirith](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/251702/why-did-aragorn-decide-to-ride-to-dunharrow-instead-of-to-minas-tirith) and Théoden is mustering the forces of Rohan there.

What makes this place so important?

Comment: How is this different from your previous question? And how are either of them not perfectly explained in the books themselves?

Comment: A question being explained in it's work has never been a reason not to ask a question. If that were the requirement this site would be quite devoid of questions.

Comment: @DanielRoseman — What was the purpose in your comment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Théoden wants a secure muster point to gather the remaining troops from across Rohan. They have to ride to Gondor all together - drips and drabs are of no use. Edoras was likely was overrun by Saruman's raiding parties while they were fleeing to Helm's Deep.

Aragorn wants to take the shortcut through the Paths of the Dead in order to  rally the forces of East Gondor and intercept Sauron's Eastern.

Answer (score 7):

With regards to its importance, Dunharrow is a secure place and is where the civilians are kept during the Battle of the Hornburg (unlike at Helm's Deep as in the films):

> ‘Hope, yes,’ said Gandalf. ‘But Isengard is strong. And other perils draw ever nearer. Do not delay, Théoden, when we are gone. **Lead your people swiftly to the Hold of Dunharrow in the hills!’**
> <sub>The Two Towers: Book III, Chapter 6: The King of the Golden Hall</sub>

> Then the king sat upon a seat before his doors, and Éowyn knelt before him and received from him a sword and a fair corslet. ‘Farewell sister-daughter!’ he said. ‘Dark is the hour, yet maybe we shall return to the Golden Hall. **But in Dunharrow the people may long defend themselves, and if the battle go ill, thither will come all who escape.’**
> <sub>ibid.</sub>

It is where the Rohirrim have decided to muster before riding to Minas Tirith. They chose to meet in Harrowdale (just below Dunharrow as can be seen in [this map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vMziM.jpg) and muster at Dunharrow due to its hidden nature and safety. Particularly, given a Nazgûl had flown over just days before. Ensuring the armies of Rohan stayed hidden was vital to keeping their secrecy.

As to why Dunharrow was built, it is rather unclear and Tolkien often changed his mind on the matter, but here is one description:

> Such was the dark Dunharrow, the work of long-forgotten men. Their name was lost and no song or legend remembered it. For what purpose they had made this place, as a town or secret temple or a tomb of kings, none in Rohan could say. Here they laboured in the Dark Years, before ever a ship came to the western shores, or Gondor of the Dúnedain was built; and now they had vanished, and only the old Púkel-men were left, still sitting at the turnings of the road.
> <sub>The Return of the King: Book V, Chapter 3: The Muster of Rohan</sub>

Answer (score 3):

The answer is that it is a [refuge](https://lotr.fandom.com/wiki/Dunharrow). As such it is hidden and defendable:

> Then the king sat upon a seat before his doors, and Éowyn knelt before him and received from him a sword and a fair corslet. 'Farewell sister-daughter!' he said. 'Dark is the hour, yet maybe we shall return to the Golden Hall. **But in Dunharrow the people may long defend themselves**, and if the battle go ill, thither will come all who escape.' 'Speak not so!' she answered. 'A year shall I endure for every day that passes until your return.' But as she spoke her eyes went to Aragorn who stood nearby.

It is on the road to the [Paths of the Dead](https://lotr.fandom.com/wiki/Paths_of_the_Dead), so Aragorn, Legolas and Gimli pass that way to access the paths. Théoden and the Rohirrim arrive there 2 days after the departure of Aragorn and company.

> And while Théoden went by slow paths in the hills, the Grey Company passed swiftly over the plain, and on the next day in the afternoon they came to Edoras; and there they halted only briefly, ere they passed up the valley, and so came to Dunharrow as darkness fell.

Théoden and the Rohirrim muster there on the orders of Théoden after Nazgûl are sighted flying between Mordor and presumably Orthanc/Isengard, passing over Edoras, making Edoras a dangerous place to gather (easily spied for intel from above).

> ‘I doubt it not,’ said the king. ‘I have had a good hill-pony made ready for you. He will bear you as swift as any horse by the roads that we shall take. For I will ride from the Burg by mountain paths, not by the plain, and so come to Edoras by way of Dunharrow where the Lady Éowyn awaits me.

As indicated in Tolkien's [map of Middle-earth](https://www.tolkiensociety.org/app/uploads/2015/11/transcribed-map.jpg), Edoras is almost in a direct line between Minas Morgul (the home of the Nazgûl) and Orthanc.

Comment: lotr.fandom is a poor resource to be quoting from and you're much better going to direct sources. They are known for adding in information that is uncited and at times utterly incorrect.

Comment: @Edlothiad, thanks. It didn't even occur to me to see if there was an online searchable text. Found one now though... time for me to re-read LOTR and edit the above!

Comment: @Edlothiad - Indeed they had one thing wrong in the info that I found - I've fixed that here and added some quotes to suit.